# postgresql подключить к андроид проекту

Tags: android, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Пишу приложение заметки.

Использую БД postgreSQL12.

Создал таблицы написал скрипты, запросы и сохранил в файл

> **note.sql**

Далее я добавил этот файл в андроид студио проект в папку **assets/note.sql**.

Так же добавил файл **app.properties**

```
driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/note
username=******
password=********
```

Читаю файл для работы с бд

```
public void init() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
     try (InputStream in = assetManager.open("app.properties")) {
            properties.load(Objects.requireNonNull(in));
            Class.forName(properties.getProperty("driver-class-name"));
            cn =  DriverManager.getConnection(
                    properties.getProperty("url"),
                    properties.getProperty("username"),
                    properties.getProperty("password")
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

Но возникает ошибка не верного подключения бд

```
E/TestRunner: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.



  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 5432) from /127.0.0.1 (port 44676) after 9999ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так?
Как работать с файлом **.sql** не удаленно(не используя серв.), а именно в с файлом, который храниться в самом приложении?

Comment: Начните с малого. Соединение команду запрос ответ ... А там дальше и файлы и всё остальное

Comment: @AzizUmarov не понял, что вы имеете ввиду ?

Comment: попробуйте для начала pgAdmin'ом на этот порт подключиться. у вас реально сервер постгреса на мобилке стоит? не слишком это затратно?

Comment: @Yakov как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474468/can-i-use-postgresql-in-android-phone#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20PostgreSQL%20port,functionality%20on%20an%20Android%20device.

Comment: вопрос в том, а зачем? чем тебя не устраивает штатный SQLite? просто ставить "полноценный" SQL-сервер ради хранения пары килобайт/мегабайт текста оно вообще оправдано?

Comment: @Yakov требования тестового задания, так бы я использовал Room

Comment: Дык, в том вопрос ты Postgres на андроиде устанавливал? проверял что он работает? ошибка-то у тебя, вероятнее всего потому возникает, что указанный порт на локалхосте никто не слушает ( иными словами служба или не установлена или не запущена ). Интересно ктож тебе такой изврат задал делать, имхо большая часть задания будет состоять из костылей по поддержке в работоспособном состоянии службы сервера / нативного кода  (баги SELinux) на более свежих андроидах.